# Re-encode/Parse logs created by log4j2, back into LogEvents

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I've created log files using log4j2 FileAppender. Without recreating my own parser, i'm trying to find a way to use what is already available to log4j2 in order to re-encode the lines within the log file back into LogEvents.

This is the FileAppender within the log4j2.xml

```
        <File name="FileAppender" fileName="Logs/urchat-${date:yyyyMMdd}.log" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
            <NoMarkerFilter onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}{UTC}UTC [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
```

I've looked at using the PatternParser, which seems like it would be the right way to go about it. I'm just not sure where to go from there. I could fall back to just manually using the delimiter (%) and splitting the line and doing it that way, it just doesn't seem like the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

[`PatternParser`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/javadoc/log4j-core/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/PatternParser.html) is probably not the class you are looking for: what it parses is **not** a log file, but a conversion pattern string like:

```
%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}{UTC}UTC [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
```

The biggest problem with parsing a log file generated by `PatterLayout` is that it is **unstructured**: you can not determine with certainty where a log event starts and where it ends.

Except the `%d` pattern, the other patterns `%t`, `%level`, `%logger`, `%msg` and the implicit `%xEx` can generate any kind of text, including line feed characters and dates. Therefore you can determine where a new log event starts (a date on a new line), but you can not determine where it ends.

To be able to parse logs in a deterministic way, you need to write them in a **structured** format like [RFC 5424](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5424), XML or JSON.